# VSCode and Golang packages and intellisence misbehaving

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-packages

I have installed Golang on my Mac with Brew. So it's the latest and greatest.
VS Code is up to date. I have installed the most recent Go extensions and ALL of the tools from the command palette.

All this seems to work. However, when I try to reference a utility package, I get no suggestions in VSCode. I assumed it would be smart enough to suggest my local package `example.go`. Correct me if that is a false assumption.

Second, since there is no suggestion via intellisense and I manually add the import as `github.com/foo/go/obs` it automatically adds a prefix of the package name in front of it resulting in this:

```
import (
   example "github.com/foo/go/obs"
)
```

Every tutorial I have seen does not have that prefix with the package name. Why is it adding `example` in from of the virtual ns? Wondering if there is a configuration I haven't hit yet?

Overall it seems like there are issues referencing packages local or external. Have to close down VSCode and then reopen and it resolves.

I have to have something misconfigured.

Here are is the output of `go env`:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/me/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/me/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/me/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/me/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.5/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.5/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/w6/d0mglhnn71x89t_y0hcy5f4w0000gn/T/go-build684279622=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

I have created a simple project. A `main.go`, a `go.mod`, and a utility I'd like to reference in the `main.go`

Here is the file structure:

[image]

main.go (before referencing my local package):

```
package main

func main() {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/foo/go

go 1.17
```

example.go

```
package example

func Do() {
    println("Hello from utility!")
}
```

main.go (after referencing local package and it adds the prefix of the package name)

```
package main

import (
   example "github.com/foo/go/obs"
)

func main() {
   example.Do() 
   println("Hello World!")
}
```

Comment: The `example` name is inserted into the import statement because the directory name doesn't match the package name, so you can better see what the package is called in the local namespace.

Comment: @JimB, thanks for that. I renamed and that prefix went away. So that is definitely helpful! Thank you.